# Android Alarm Manager isn't working on proper time

Tags: java, android

I am using **AlarmManager** to do some scheduling task. My problem is, it's not working as it should do. Like, I want to set time for show a **toast message** ]. If I set, It will be show after 5,10 or 20 minutes. It works fine. But, If I set after 1 hour it will show a toast message.Sometimes, It works properly and sometimes not.Maximum times,it failed.It showed the message right after I hit the set button. I am unable to figure out the problem.Here is my code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SetSchedule.this,ScheduleReceiver.class);
larmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcas(SetSchedule.this, 1, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

So, how can I solve the problem ?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with API level 19... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @Vyger mine minimum -16 and traget-18